# Solr Spatial Search : Can we obtain the coordinates of the rectangle containing all the results

Tags: solr, geospatial

I have a large Solr collection of documents. Each of these documents have a SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType field to hold their location/shape. This is just fine for narrowing any query to a specific geographic area.

The very first query though (in the scenario i'd like to offer) does not provide any geographic restriction. But still, **I'd like to know the coordinates of the rectangle that contains all of the results**. This would allow me to initialize my Leaflet map with meaningful boundaries.

The facet functions (min/max) don't seem to work with spatial fields...

If anybody knows how to get that information...

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Index the coordinates to two separate fields as just float/double values? Those would be suitable for faceting/stats

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh ! Seems to be the easiest way to get what I want.